# Decomposing HTML to link text and target

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

Given an HTML link like

```
<a href="urltxt" class="someclass" close="true">texttxt</a>
```

how can I isolate the url and the text?

**Updates**

I'm using Beautiful Soup, and am unable to figure out how to do that.

I did

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))

links = soup.findAll('a')

for link in links:
    print "link content:", link.content," and attr:",link.attrs
```

i get

```
*link content: None  and attr: [(u'href', u'_redirectGeneric.asp?genericURL=/root    /support.asp')]*  ...
...
```

Why am i missing the content?

edit: elaborated on 'stuck' as advised :)

Comment: Chances are there's a problem with urllib.urlopen(url).  Try printing that out and see what you get.  It should be the straight HTML of the web page.

Comment: Also, "stuck!" is not very descriptive.  Show more code and what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, it made it much easier to see what was happening.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [Beautiful Soup](http://crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup).  Doing it yourself is harder than it looks, you'll be better off using a tried and tested module.

**EDIT:**

I think you want:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

By the way, it's a bad idea to try opening the URL there, as if it goes wrong it could get ugly.

**EDIT 2:**

This should show you all the links in a page:

```
import urlparse, urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.example.com/index.html"
source = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source)

for item in soup.fetchall('a'):
    try:
        link =  urlparse.urlparse(item['href'].lower())
    except:
        # Not a valid link
        pass
    else:
        print link
```

Comment: I agree, Beatiful Soup is probably the better way to handle this.

Comment: would it be better to open the url elsewhere and check for errors there itself?

Comment: Yes, and have a try...except around it just in case it fails.

Comment: The 'u' before the string means it is in Unicode.  See wikipedia for what that means.  It shouldn't affect you too much.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a code example, showing getting the attributes and contents of the links:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.attrs, link.contents
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have two issues there:

1. link.content**s**, not link.content
2. attrs is a dictionary, not a string. It holds key value pairs for each attribute in an HTML element. link.attrs['href'] will get you what you appear to be looking for, but you'd want to wrap that in a check in case you come across an a tag without an href attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Though I suppose the others *might* be correct in pointing you to using Beautiful Soup, they *might* not, and using an external library might be massively over-the-top for your purposes. Here's a regex which will do what you ask.

```
/<a\s+[^>]*?href="([^"]*)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>/
```

Here's what it matches:

```
'<a href="url" close="true">text</a>'
// Parts: "url", "text"

'<a href="url" close="true">text<span>something</span></a>'
// Parts: "url", "text<span>something</span>"
```

If you wanted to get *just* the text (eg: "textsomething" in the second example above), I'd just run another regex over it to strip anything between pointed brackets.

Comment: With this approach you need to watch out for line breaks in the source code.  Make sure you set the flag re.DOTALL when you compile your pattern.