# Parse URL from plain text

Tags: python, url, parsing

How can I parse URLs from any give plain text (not limited to href attributes in  tags)?

Any code examples in Python will be appreciated.

Comment: See near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Jan Goyvaerts' blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20230420024533/http://www.regexguru.com/2008/11/detecting-urls-in-a-block-of-text/).

So a Python code example could look like

```
result = re.findall(r"\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]", subject)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to parse the string.

Look in this previously asked question:
[What’s the cleanest way to extract URLs from a string using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python)