# Python Twitter - Get tweet URLS

Tags: python, django, python-twitter

I am using the python-twitter module to get my most recent twitter status updates:

```
for i in range(0, limit):
        tweet = twitter.Api().GetUserTimeline(TWITTER_USERNAME)[i]
        tweet.date = datetime.strptime( tweet.created_at, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y" )
        tweets.append(tweet)
```

It's working fine, but the tweet.text property does not wrap the URL in a tags so they are clickable. I had a look through the python-twitter documentation but it doesn't give any specific advise on getting a status with the URLs as clickable urls.

I'm sure there is a function in the library to do this, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely have to parse the text to find and mark up the URLs yourself. Here's a question about that:

[What's the cleanest way to extract URLs from a string using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python)