# How to remove any URL within a string in Python

Tags: python, regex, url, replace, python-2.7

I want to remove all URLs inside a string (replace them with "")
I searched around but couldn't really find what I want.

Example:

```
text1
text2
http://url.com/bla1/blah1/
text3
text4
http://url.com/bla2/blah2/
text5
text6
http://url.com/bla3/blah3/
```

I want the result to be:

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
```

Comment: Are you sure you've researched sufficiently? Have you tried **regular expressions**?

Comment: Yes but I didn't really understand how to do it in my example..

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python

Answer (score 95, accepted):

***Python script:***

```
import re
text = re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

***Output:***

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6
```

*Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/K3Cut).*

Comment: This solution assumes that any URL is immediately follows by a new line (which is the case in the OP's example, but just FYI). tolgayilmaz's [regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823105/395857) doesn't have this potential shortcoming.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Interesting because this was not the case for the twitter dataset I am working with. Above code removed all urls despite them not being immediately followed by a new line

Answer (score 116):

the shortest way

```
re.sub(r'http\S+', '', stringliteral)
```

Comment: This will also remove 'httpabc' and 'abchttp'.

Comment: @LouisYang huh? it shouldn't (and doesn't; at least on 3.7) remove abchttp. You'd have to use `.*http` or something like that. 

BTW, I'd suggest `r'https?://\S+'`.

Comment: this is the best solution and should be marked as the right answer

Comment: You can also write it like `text = re.sub(r"\S*https?:\S*", "", text)` to remove the https even if they're in paranthesis or brackets.

Comment: @henley, above code did not work for my text: '''$0.29 non-gaap diluted income per share. [$29 million after tax] on the revaluation,
http : //www.businesswire.com/news/home/20210217005928/en .-AAAAA-santa clara,"""

Comment: @tursunWali i think it's because of the space in your link but i'm not sure?

Comment: The above solution will also remove 'httpabc' etc, to overcome that, you can use something like `re.sub(r'http\S*:{1}/{2}\S+', '', sentence)`

Comment: same here. didn't work on several tweets when used in a function. ```re.sub(r'^https?:\/\/.*[\r\n]*', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)``` worked

Answer (score 30):

This worked for me:

```
import re
thestring = "text1\ntext2\nhttp://url.com/bla1/blah1/\ntext3\ntext4\nhttp://url.com/bla2/blah2/\ntext5\ntext6"

URLless_string = re.sub(r'\w+:\/{2}[\d\w-]+(\.[\d\w-]+)*(?:(?:\/[^\s/]*))*', '', thestring)
print URLless_string
```

Result:

```
text1
text2

text3
text4

text5
text6
```

Answer (score 19):

## Removal of HTTP links/URLs mixed up in any text:

```
import re
re.sub(r'''(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))''', " ", text)
```

Comment: This method hangs for me when parsing a string with '[<link>](<link>)'. Any idea why?

Comment: above method worked for me. I think this is most comprehensive solution.

Comment: just a stern warning, i attempted to use this exact regex to remove URLS from a ve...eeery long text in ONE , just ONE record in swifter + pandas dataframe. and after waiting for hours it didn't seem to end... then I used this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/38498442/1465073, and the same text took like a fraction of a second to finish. I lost like 12-24 hours worth of work just trying to figure out what was happening. No errors, no warnings, just my apply function seemingly frozen for hours. Im using 13700K, 2 x 16 DDR5 6000, RTX 4090. The same issue manifested in Azure cloud A100 and V100s

Answer (score 18):

This solution caters for http, https and the other normal url type special characters :

```
import re
def remove_urls (vTEXT):
    vTEXT = re.sub(r'(https|http)?:\/\/(\w|\.|\/|\?|\=|\&|\%)*\b', '', vTEXT, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    return(vTEXT)


print( remove_urls("this is a test https://sdfs.sdfsdf.com/sdfsdf/sdfsdf/sd/sdfsdfs?bob=%20tree&jef=man lets see this too https://sdfsdf.fdf.com/sdf/f end"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the URL content a hyphen, e.g. `print(remove_urls("this https://sdfs-sdfsdf.com yo"))` -> `this is a test -sdfsdf.com yo`

Comment: Use this instead (r'(https|http)?:\/\/(\w|\.|\/|\?|\=|\&|\%|\-)*\b'

Comment: I like the idea of this, but why is `(http|https)` optional? Do any URLs begin with `://`?
I have had decent success with `(https|http|ftp):\/\/\S+`

Answer (score 15):

I wasn't able to find any that handled my particular situation, which was removing *urls in the middle* of tweets that also have *whitespaces in the middle of urls* so I made my own:

```
(https?:\/\/)(\s)*(www\.)?(\s)*((\w|\s)+\.)*([\w\-\s]+\/)*([\w\-]+)((\?)?[\w\s]*=\s*[\w\%&]*)*
```

here's an explanation:
`(https?:\/\/)` matches http:// or https://
`(\s)*` optional whitespaces
`(www\.)?` optionally matches www.
`(\s)*` optionally matches whitespaces
`((\w|\s)+\.)*` matches 0 or more of one or more word characters followed by a period
`([\w\-\s]+\/)*` matches 0 or more of one or more words(or a dash or a space) followed by '\'
`([\w\-]+)` any remaining path at the end of the url followed by an optional ending
`((\?)?[\w\s]*=\s*[\w\%&]*)*` matches ending query params (even with white spaces,etc)

test this out here:https://regex101.com/r/NmVGOo/8

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the explanation. Links can go dead.

Comment: @Gabriel, I have modified your code a little bit so that it works for both http and https:   (?:(https|http)\s?:\/\/)(\s)*(www\.)?(\s)*((\w|\s)+\.)*([\w\-\s]+\/)*([\w\-]+)((\?)?[\w\s]*=\s*[\w\%&]*)*

Comment: @tursunWali it already works for http and https, please see the attached testing link. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

What you really want to do is to remove any string that starts with either `http://` or `https://` plus any combination of non white space characters. Here is how I would solve it. My solution is very similar to that of @tolgayilmaz

```
#Define the text from which you want to replace the url with "".
text ='''The link to this post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331982/how-to-remove-any-url-within-a-string-in-python'''

import re
#Either use:
re.sub('http://\S+|https://\S+', '', text)
#OR 
re.sub('http[s]?://\S+', '', text)
```

And the result of running either code above is

```
>>> 'The link to this post is '
```

I prefer the second one because it is more readable.

Comment: what if there is   white space characters like : http : //www.businesswire.com/news/home/20210217005928/en .

Comment: Hmmm! will that still be a url?

Comment: if we want to remove such word groups from file, then what to do? (if I modify my question)

Comment: I think that would be a new and different question. Not the one being asked here. My answer is for the question that was posted here.

Answer (score 8):

In order to **remove any URL** within a **string in Python**, you can use this RegEx function :

```
import re

def remove_URL(text):
    """Remove URLs from a text string"""
    return re.sub(r"http\S+", "", text)
```

Comment: this is should be the best answer!

Answer (score 7):

I know this has already been answered and its stupid late but I think this should be here. This is a regex that matches any kind of url.

```
[^ ]+\.[^ ]+
```

It can be used like

```
re.sub('[^ ]+\.[^ ]+','',sentence)
```

Comment: This is only a regex, this does not replace anything and thus this isn't answering the question.

Comment: @AndréKool this is for matching any kind of url. for replacing there are already alot of answers above

Comment: In that case i suggest you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49257661/edit) your answer to explain that to avoid any confusion.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks! It is a very elegant and eficient solution to match url starting with and without http(s) and www.

Comment: indeed , very elegant and simple solution, covers ALL cases, thank you man

Answer (score 6):

You could also look at it from the other way around...

```
from urlparse import urlparse
[el for el in ['text1', 'FTP://somewhere.com', 'text2', 'http://blah.com:8080/foo/bar#header'] if not urlparse(el).scheme]
```

Answer (score 3):

The following regular expression in **Python** works well for ***detecting URL(s)*** in the text:

```
source_text = '''
text1
text2
http://url.com/bla1/blah1/
text3
text4
http://url.com/bla2/blah2/
text5
text6    '''

import re
url_reg  = r'[a-z]*[:.]+\S+'
result   = re.sub(url_reg, '', source_text)
print(result)
```

**Output**:

```
text1
text2

text3
text4

text5
text6
```

Comment: The question was answered 5 years ago. What new value does your answer bring?

Comment: This will delete lines like `text1:text2`, that is not wanted.

Answer (score 1):

why do not use this its so complete

```
i = re.sub(r"(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)","",i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
s = '''
text1
text2
http://url.com/bla1/blah1/
text3
text4
http://url.com/bla2/blah2/
text5
text6
http://url.com/bla3/blah3/'''
g = re.findall(r'(text\d+)',s)
print ('list',g)
for i in g:
    print (i)
```

Out

```
list ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4', 'text5', 'text6']
text1
text2
text3
text4
text5
text6    ​
```

Comment: The text is just an example, not a keyword. It can be any sentence or word.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most general URL regex pattern is this one:

```py
URL_PATTERN = r'[A-Za-z0-9]+://[A-Za-z0-9%-_]+(/[A-Za-z0-9%-_])*(#|\\?)[A-Za-z0-9%-_&=]*'
```

There is a small module that does what do you want:

```sh
pip install mysmallutils
```

```py
from mysutils.text import remove_urls

remove_urls(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple .* with a positive look behind should do the job.

```
text="text1\ntext2\nhttp://url.com/bla1/blah1/\ntext3\ntext4\nhttp://url.com/bla2/blah2/\ntext5\ntext6"

req=re.sub(r'http.*?(?=\s)', " ", text)
print(req)
```