# Replacing various links that contain common text string with one single link

Tags: html, regex

I've just discovered RegEx and using Dreamweaver to try and update hundreds of pages on our intranet. The paths have one folder in common for my search - e.g. "hawww"

```
<a href="http://home/hawww/test1.asp">line1</a>
<a href="http://home/hawww/sample.html">page3</a>
<a href="hawww.html">line3</a>
<a href="www.hawww/test2.html">line4</a>
```

I would want to change all of those links to something like:

```
<a href="sample.html">
```

I can change them where the link starts with the same text, but not where it doesn't - if that makes sense. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Jonathan

Comment: So you would like to replace all links with the substring hawww with links to sample.html?

Comment: take a look at this python example and utilize the RegEx in a similar way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331982/how-to-remove-any-url-within-a-string-in-python

Comment: [These things are harder than they look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

I did a quick and dirty test. You can run these through vim or whatever RegEx tool you use. Essentially, the search regex should be this:

```
/href=\".*?hawww.*?"/g
```

### Explanation

`.*?` means search for anything, but don't use greedy matching. The `g` at the end is an optional flag for global matching.

### Test Case

Here is a test JS script I used.

```
var test = ['<a href="http://home/hawww/test1.asp">line1</a>',
  '<a href="http://home/hawww/sample.html">page3</a>',
  '<a href="hawww.html">line3</a>',
  '<a href="www.hawww/test2.html">line4</a>'];

var fixed = test.map(function(html) {
    return html.replace(/href=\".*?hawww.*?"/, 'href="simple.html"');    
});

console.log(fixed);
```

### Mass Change

You can use a tool like `sed` to perform all the changes on your files. However, I recommend backing up and doing some testing afterwards before committing the changes. There may be some odd use cases where `hawww` is used in a link and you want to keep it there.

```
sed -i 's/href=\".*?hawww.*?"/href="simple.html"/g' /home/user/*.html
```

Comment: I tried /href=\".*?hawww.*?"/g in Dreamweavers Find and Replace, but no luck... The link I tried it it on is <a href="http://portal/portal/server.pt?open=space&name=CommunityPage&id=7&cached=true&control=SetCommunity&PageID=0&CommunityID=914&WG_link=http://portalweb/reddot/hawww/live/propertyfacilitiessecurity/42008.asp">Meeting and conferencing facilities and travel services</A>

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't know enough about Dreamweaver. I know that each application is responsible for implementing their own regex engine. Try escaping the search: `/href=\\\".*?hawww.*?/g`. Sometimes you don't need the `g` option and there's a tickbox that says global.