# Remove a URL row by row from a large set of text in python panda dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, spyder

i have inserted data into pandas dataframe. like the picture suggest 
as you can see there are some rows that contain url links  i want to remove all the url links and replace them with " " (nothing just wiping it )  [image: dataframe] as you can see row 4 has a url there are other rows too that have url. i want to go through all the rows in the status_message column find any url and remove them. i've been looking at this [How to remove any URL within a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331982/how-to-remove-any-url-within-a-string-in-python) but am not sure how to use to it on the dataframe. so row 4 should like vote for labour register now.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `case=False` parameter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'status_message':['a s sd Www.labour.com',
                                    'httP://lab.net dud ff a',
                                     'a ss HTTPS://dd.com ur o']})
print (df)
             status_message
0     a s sd Www.labour.com
1   httP://lab.net dud ff a
2  a ss HTTPS://dd.com ur o

df['status_message'] = df['status_message'].str.replace('http\S+|www.\S+', '', case=False)
print (df)
  status_message
0        a s sd 
1       dud ff a
2     a ss  ur o
```

Comment: Yes, very similar, only one difference there is - `case=False` for case insensitive.

Comment: plus one for `case = False`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()` with regex to do that i.e

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Nice to meet you www.xy.com amazing','Wow https://www.goal.com','Amazing http://Goooooo.com']})
df['A'] = df['A'].replace(r'http\S+', '', regex=True).replace(r'www\S+', '', regex=True)
```

Output :

```
                           A
0  Nice to meet you amazing
1                       Wow 
2                   Amazing
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something simple as

```
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    desc = row['status_message'].lower().split()
    print ' '.join(word for word in desc if not word.startswith(('www.','http')))
```

as long as the urls start with "www."

Answer (score 0):

df.status_message = df.status_message.str.replace("www.", "")