# Expression to remove URL links from Twitter tweet

Tags: python, regex, string

I simply would like to find and replace all occurrences of a twitter url in a string (tweet):

Input:

> This is a tweet with a url: http://t.co/0DlGChTBIx

Output:

> This is a tweet with a url:

I've tried this:

```
p=re.compile(r'\<http.+?\>', re.DOTALL)
tweet_clean = re.sub(p, '', tweet)
```

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python

Comment: For this specific case you can do: `your_string.replace('http://t.co/0DlGChTBIx','')`

Comment: I've tried a bunch of different regex expressions not working...

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx for url regex

Comment: @Marcin That made my day :-D

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Do this:

```
result = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", subject)
```

- `http` matches literal characters
- `\S+` matches all non-whitespace characters (the end of the url)
- we replace with the empty string

Comment: It will remove any string prefix with http  e.g. httparty

Comment: What is `re`, `subject` and is `result` a constant?

Answer (score 2):

The following regex will capture two matched groups: the first includes everything in the tweet until the url and the second will catch everything that will come after the URL (empty in the example you posted above):

```
import re
str = 'This is a tweet with a url: http://t.co/0DlGChTBIx'
clean_tweet = re.match('(.*?)http.*?\s?(.*?)', str)
if clean_tweet: 
    print clean_tweet.group(1)
    print clean_tweet.group(2) # will print everything after the URL
```

Comment: You asked the output to be: "This is a tweet with a url:" and that's what it does. Do you want to extract only the URL ?

Comment: string = "niki minaj - anaconda:hhttp://youtu.be/LDZX4ooRsWs @tv1 #niki this is cool!"  ( trying to take out the url, the (at)mention and the #hashtag and leave everything else )

Comment: @sirvon can you add this test-case with an expected output to the question?

Answer (score 2):

you can use:

```
text = 'Amazing save #FACup #zeebox https://stackoverflow.com/tiUya56M Ok'
text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/\S*', '', text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

# output: 'Amazing save #FACup #zeebox  Ok'
```

- `r` The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with 'r'
- `?` Causes the resulting RE to match 0 or 1 repetitions of the preceding RE. https? will match either ‘http’ or ‘https’.
- `https?:\/\/` will match any "http://" and "https://" in string
- `\S` Returns a match where the string DOES NOT contain a white space character
- `*` Zero or more occurrences

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below re.sub function to remove URL link from your string,

```
>>> str = 'This is a tweet with a url: http://t.co/0DlGChTBIx'
>>> m = re.sub(r':.*$', ":", str)
>>> m
'This is a tweet with a url:'
```

It removes everything after first `:` symbol and `:` in the replacement string would add `:` at the last.

This would prints all the characters which are just before to the `:` symbol,

```
>>> m = re.search(r'^.*?:', str).group()
>>> m
'This is a tweet with a url:'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text = re.sub(r"https:(\/\/t\.co\/([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z]){10})", "", text)
```

This matches alphanumerics  too after `t.co/`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
text = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

clean_tweet = re.match('(.*?)http(.*?)\s(.*)', content)
    while (clean_tweet):
        content = clean_tweet.group(1) + " " + clean_tweet.group(3)
        clean_tweet = re.match('(.*?)http(.*?)\s(.*)', content)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
text = re.sub(r'https?://\S+|www\.\S+', '', text)
```