# Resolving Catastrophic Backtracking issue in RegEx

Tags: python, regex, url, ip-address, ipv4

I am using RegEx for finding URL substrings in strings.
The RegEx I am using has been taken from tohster's answer on -
[What's the cleanest way to extract URLs from a string using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520031/whats-the-cleanest-way-to-extract-urls-from-a-string-using-python/30408189#30408189)

The RE is -

```
r'^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$'
```

I have done some changes to it -

> 1. In the IPv4 detection part, I changed the order of the IP range to be found. > Precisely, changed `[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3]` to `25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-> 9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]` at 2 instances.
> 2. Made the https group - `(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)` optional.

The final version is -

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?
```

The final RE I am using seems to be very promising and has improved significantly as per my requirements(as compared to the original one) and works in Python as well as Java Script, except for the fact that due to the changes I have done have caused the following examples to give `"catastrophic backtracking"` error -

> asasasasasac31.23.53.122asasassasd
>
> 12312312312321.32.34.2312312312321
>
> 12.3423423432.234123123.123
>
> 31.134232131.231.34

Can be tested at - https://regex101.com/r/i6jDei/1

My contention is that the first example - `asasasasasac31.23.53.122asasassasd` should have some slick way to pass as the IP is surrounded by non-numeric chars.

Also, is there a way to pass the first two of the above examples as valid IPv4 addresses?

To resolve ambiguity, I would opt for the largest possible Address, i.e.,

> 31.23.53.122
>
> 21.32.34.231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue of the catastrophic backtracking is caused by the pattern `(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,}))` where `(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)` will jump through a lot of combinations, if the overall pattern can not be matched. As you can see the character classes are basically the same, so e.g. for `asasasasasac31` it can match like:

```
(asasasasasac31)
(a)(sasasasasac31)
(a)(s)(asasasasac31)
(as)(asasasasac31)
```

This is not really the way it actually takes, just to show how many combinations exist.

The mistake here seems to be the `-` being optional which I see no reason for. If we remove the -, we get it working for your samples (and reduce the number of steps for the already working samples).

See the updated [regex101-demo](https://regex101.com/r/i6jDei/3), where I also added your samples that caused the catastrophic backtracking.

The final pattern then is:

```
(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?
```

Comment: very well presented answer

Comment: Thanks for the finding ! I have a lot of URLs with '-' characters. They are partially outputted and not the complete URL. See https://regex101.com/r/REu26j/1 . Is it a consequence of the change you made? What shall I do to get full URLs

Comment: @user1412066 if I input the first of your examples to your old pattern, the match is the same. For the second it shows catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: It seems the double `-` is the issue, you might want to replace the two occurences of `-` in your pattern with `-+`

Comment: Thanks ! I added [-_]+ at two places to get it working for "hyphens" and "underscores". Can we always find a way out of Cat. Backtracking? I think not.

Comment: @user1412066 Well this obviously depends on the input and what one actually wants to achieve, but I'd say that at least 99,9% of catastrophic backtracking can be solved. This might include a total rework of the used pattern.